# passing data into a class

Tags: python, function, class

Im working on my project for my Intro to python class and I have been trying all day to figure out why I cant get my coordinates to pass into this function, and just keep hitting roadblocks.

```
class GeoPoint:
    def __init__(self, lat=0, lon=0, description= 'TBD'):
        self.__lat = lat
        self.__lon = lon
        self.description = description

    def SetPoint(self,coords):
        self.lat = coords[0]
        self.lon = coords[1]

    def GetPoint(self):
        return self.__lat, self.__lon

    def SetDescription(self, my_description):
        self.description = my_description

    def GetDescription(self):
        return self.description

    # Function to calculate distance
    def distance(self, toPoint):
        R = 3958.8  # Radius of earth in miles
        lat1 = radians(self.lat)
        lon1 = radians(self.lon)
        lat2 = radians(self.lat)
        lon2 = radians(self.lon)
        dlon = lon2 - lon1
        dlat = lat2 - lat1
        a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        d = R * c
        return d

    Point = property(GetPoint, SetPoint)
    Description = property(GetDescription, SetDescription)
```

Above is the class that im trying to use and ive already set 2 locations using the Geopoint class. I ask the user for their coordinates and a description of the location. but anytime i print the userpoint it shows the proper coordinates but if i attempt to do anything with them i just get 0 from the distance function. Im thinking my issue is in the SetPoint function and its not passing to that because im not exactly understanding how to pass the info to that.

```
# Program Code
user_lat = float(input("Please enter your current latitude. "))
user_lon = float(input("Please enter your current longitude. "))
user_description = str(input("Please enter a description of your Location. "))
userpoint = user_lat, user_lon
user_coords = userpoint.Point

abq_distance = ABQ.distance(user_coords)
tuc_distance = TUC.distance(user_coords)
```

Comment: It doesn't look like `distance` is using the `toPoint` parameter at all, so you might want to double check what that code is actually doing.

Comment: Thats kind of what im asking, im not understanding why they want the toPoint or what to do with it.

Comment: Line 5 in your program code, a `tuple` has no `Point` attribute!

Comment: @Shib yes im aware, that doesnt have anything to do with the question unfortunately. i was just trying stuff im aware of the error that line causes and im trying to figure out how to get the data into the distance function. The assignment wants the (toPoint) in the distance function but as someone else has mentioned its not being used and im not exactly understanding how to use it, so im assuming my issue here has something to do with the toPoint and the GetPoint and SetPoint functions but im not able to figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at the first 4 lines of the `distance` function. You are calculating the distance between 2 of the same points! The new function would be:

```py
def distance(self, point2):
        if(not isinstance(point2, type(self)): return
        R = 3958.8  # Radius of earth in miles
        lat1 = radians(self.__lat)
        lon1 = radians(self.__lon)
        lat2 = radians(point2.__lat)
        lon2 = radians(point2.__lon)
        dlon = lon2 - lon1
        dlat = lat2 - lat1
        a = sin(dlat / 2) ** 2 + cos(lat1) * cos(lat2) * sin(dlon / 2) ** 2
        c = 2 * atan2(sqrt(a), sqrt(1 - a))
        d = R * c
        return d
```

Comment: were getting a little closer, but now we still have the tuple issue, ive tried doing it with `userpoint = GeoPoint(user_lat, user_lon, user_description)` that gives me a not subscriptable error, and i tried with `userpoint = user_lat, user_lon
usercoords = userpoint.SetPoint(userpoint)` and that gives me a tuple error, im not understanding how to get user_lat and user_lon into the functions.

Comment: So let me clarify, in this new distance function, you are passing a `GeoPoint` instance as the point2, correct?

Comment: If that's what you want, I have updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have some typos, but I'm not seeing anyplace where you're correctly creating the GeoPoint class with valid init data:

`user_coords = userpoint.Point`

If this is supposed to be a reference to GeoPoint, then it should be:

```
user_coords = GeoPoint(*userpoint)
# or
user_coords = GeoPoint(user_lat, user_lon)
```

Comment: this is what ive tried using for the geopoint

userpoint = GeoPoint(user_lat, user_lon, user_description)

When i try to pass userpoint into the disctance function via 

abq_distance = ABQ.distance(userpoint) 

I get GeoPoint  object has no attribute lat

Comment: @MatthewVanDruff the reason why you are getting this error is because you are forgetting to access the same property _each_ and _every_ time. You should always be accessing `self.__lat`, and `self.__lon`.